# Error while using a DLL in an ASP application

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I started working on a project which shows an error which I describe below with the lines:

```
' VBScript
Set lLogOn = Server.CreateObject("RuleEngine26.Transact") 
' They have a DLL named RuleEngine26.dll and are creating object out of it
' They put functions like dbconnection inside of it
' There is no source code for it, only the DLL is available

' VBScript
lprofile = lLogOn.PerformTxn(lChnlId, lAppId,"SignOn","",lUserId,lxmlrequest) 
' Here they are calling a function and it returns XML
' The expected XML should contain 4 child nodes but I am getting none back
```

How do I solve these issues?

Comment: Does it have documentation? Maybe they expose some sort of error mechanism e.g. `lLogOn.GetLastError()` that will let you know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If by "it returns a xml" you mean the `PerformTxn` method returns an XML object such as MSXML2 DOMDocument or Element then you are missing a `Set` statement:-

```
Set lprofile = lLogOn.PerformTxn(lChnlId, lAppId,"SignOn","",lUserId,lxmlrequest)
```